# Want to hide password typing

Tags: javascript, html

This code complete hide my html.but the problem is when i type its shown the pass what i typing in the type box.i just want to hide while i am typing like facebook,gmail etc.i just want to modify my code.

This code complete hide my html.but the problem is when i type its shown the pass what i typing in the type box.i just want to hide while i am typing like facebook,gmail etc.i just want to modify my code.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--


function get_password() {
  var orig_pass = prompt("Please enter password","");
  if (orig_pass!=null && orig_pass!="")
  var password = new Array(orig_pass.length);
  for(i=0; i<orig_pass.length; i++) {
    password[i] = orig_pass.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return password;
}

function zubrag_decode() {
var password = get_password();
var orig = unescape("".concat('%7B%3CmR%3Cmim%20Blomnm%22Be%3Etdr%20dmvma%20ipl%3Cmcgnsec%22%22%20te%20s%3C/%3Ebi2/cpr2%3Dah6tcd3%3C/a6s7sctks%3D-o2gbearou%3E-.ioe/.i%3Bemlmggohpstinm1s9th/m%3E/FeooltTna%3CCm/ooSeaGlepme%22e%3Cmpom',
'sm%20m%3Cla.ln%20%22it/h%3E%22m5%20%22mbtbderw%22d%22mmm4%209%20%20%3Cobdd%09%3Dm0m%3E%20m%20F%20-%20rtmomy%20m%20F%20%20%20%3C%20d%3Cwmdmm%3D%204%202%20%3ERdmt%20%20ligt%3Dmc%3E6t%22r%3C%3Eim%3D%20ci',
'%20n%20%22%20e%20mhm%22mmmm%20%20%20%20%20y%20%3C%20d%3Cvrm%3Ams%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%3C%20ir%3E%20md%20%22-yr%20r%20%22%20afion%3Aic%3DnmeF%22cmm%20%20l%20g%20%3D%20a%20lt%20ri%3Epmt9tm%20e%20%22',
'%20e%20tg%20Rnmu%3D%20myNrmht%20xl%22cnh%3Ely%22ry%22aoertneaee.o%3Edm%3D%20mY%20u%20%20%20a%20e%20b%22nmum%20%20y%20ec%20f%20l%20%22%3CnmmFt%22typi%3De%3E%3E%3Cem%20%20a%20e%20%20%20%21F%20l%3C%22nmu',
'%22%20m%20p%20%3D%20s%20baiei%20patut%3DeUt%22oudmFtl%20%22olme%20%22%20p%20m%20c%20%20ioec%20i/kl%20t%20i%20.%20a%20uFn%27lpco%3Ddmnss.v%3Blme%20m%20ol%20a%20i%20g%20e%20%3Em%20m%20%20g%20o%20lt%20s%',
'20r%20p%20.%3Cuc%20wotgSec%3DeyiHtnrlnrefgheupcosdpdrdme%20%28%20i%20%3D%20ml%20a%20e%20%29%20.%20y%20.%20p%20o%20d%20it%20s%20t%20i%20.pamlnaNFdl%29imph%20s%20p%20r%20m%20so%20e%20%3B%20m%20%20%20%3C',
'%20t%20r%20%20%20a%20st%20%22%20m%20mr%20e%20ln%20f%20l%3Cefvrxmm%20m%20%20%20%20a%20b%20%20/%3Coim%20mda%20o%20t%20u%20%22%20%3Codiv%3Eim%3D%20h%20Fp%20t%20%3E%20/sUr/mtmm%20m%20%20%27%20B%20n%3Ctcoi',
'%20%20immU%20l%20afe%20%28yianuf%29l%7Bcmmo%20d%20d%20s%20ioesm%20nm.meaE%22%20m%20ndBcIU%28mtygotml%29msutly.di%27p%20a%23r%3D%27%27.oteu%3B%7Ddms%20l%20y%20%28%20%3Encnm%27nm.te%3C%20l%20m%20ndB%20I',
'me%27tugptt%20%29genteyHdMu%20%3Etsua%27u.%3B%3Emmr%20T%20Lm%3Dm%20%20pt%20s%20m%20m%3Cms1%7Dimt%20m%20m%20%201%20%20%20%20/%3Cctulg%3Emmm%20i%20pvts%20%20siypea%20%3Ai%20onku%20%20a%3Eggs%3Al2ypb%3Bc',
'%7Do%3Bmmmrmi%20p%20l0%20x%20%20%3Cmstygm%3E%20m%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/ht%3El/edtmm%20%20%20%20%20%20e%3Crrr%3Cmtm%3E%20F%20m%20t%20o%20y/mem%3Em%3C%20t%20b%3Ce%20mtd%20%3E%3Cm3%20%26%20b%20a%3Bl',
'/%3E3mmumhh%3C%3E%3Ennsse%3Bvhp%3Emmm%20/oin%26mbmpm%3Cmnm%20mm%3C%20d%20v%3Ct%20%3Em%20m%22mmmm%20%20%20%20pu%3Ditm%3E%22e%20%22%20e.%20/%20b%3Deodmm%20%20%20p/mmo%20dy%20%20ma%20%20%20%22pc%20.rp%22',
'%3Cyenu%20m.%20%20ep%22%3Bme%20os%3E/m%3El%20%20t%20El%7B%3E%20mm%3Ee%20m%28mlmi'));
orig = orig.split("");

var passnum = orig.length % password.length;
for(i=orig.length-1; i>=0; i--) {

  passnum--;
  if (passnum == -1) passnum = password.length - 1;
  
  var pos1 = i;
  var pos2 = i + password[passnum];

  if (pos2 >= orig.length) continue;

  char1 = orig[pos1];
  char2 = orig[pos2];

  orig[pos2] = char1;
  orig[pos1] = char2;

}

var orig1 = "";
for(i=0;i<orig.length;i++) {
  orig1 = orig1 + orig[i];
}
orig1 = orig1.replace(/mmm/g,"\r\n");

document.getElementById("zubrag-block1").innerHTML = orig1;
}

//-->

</script>
<noscript>JavaScript must be enabled in your browser in order to view the protected page.</noscript>
<div id="zubrag-block1"><input type="button" value="Click to unblock" onclick="zubrag_decode();"/></div
```

Comment: I'm not sure that can be done in `prompt` prompts. For real applications, you'd use an `input` element with `password` type, or something that emulates that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yeah, I agree. Don't think it's possible with `prompt`. You could perhaps make a modal dialog out of the ye olde floating div (or use a library for that) and then have the password input there.

Answer (score 3):

`window.prompt()` cannot mask the input. You would need to choose another options for the input:

1. a `<input type="password" />` HTML tag

or

2. basic HTTP authorization (you have to send appropriate headers from the backend to do this)

I edited your code to get password from an input instead of a prompt:

```html
<input id="password-input" type="password" />
<button onclick="zubrag_decode()">Click me</button>

<div id="zubrag-block1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function zubrag_decode() {
var password = document.getElementById('password-input').value;
var orig = unescape("".concat('%7B%3CmR%3Cmim%20Blomnm%22Be%3Etdr%20dmvma%20ipl%3Cmcgnsec%22%22%20te%20s%3C/%3Ebi2/cpr2%3Dah6tcd3%3C/a6s7sctks%3D-o2gbearou%3E-.ioe/.i%3Bemlmggohpstinm1s9th/m%3E/FeooltTna%3CCm/ooSeaGlepme%22e%3Cmpom',
'sm%20m%3Cla.ln%20%22it/h%3E%22m5%20%22mbtbderw%22d%22mmm4%209%20%20%3Cobdd%09%3Dm0m%3E%20m%20F%20-%20rtmomy%20m%20F%20%20%20%3C%20d%3Cwmdmm%3D%204%202%20%3ERdmt%20%20ligt%3Dmc%3E6t%22r%3C%3Eim%3D%20ci',
'%20n%20%22%20e%20mhm%22mmmm%20%20%20%20%20y%20%3C%20d%3Cvrm%3Ams%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%3C%20ir%3E%20md%20%22-yr%20r%20%22%20afion%3Aic%3DnmeF%22cmm%20%20l%20g%20%3D%20a%20lt%20ri%3Epmt9tm%20e%20%22',
'%20e%20tg%20Rnmu%3D%20myNrmht%20xl%22cnh%3Ely%22ry%22aoertneaee.o%3Edm%3D%20mY%20u%20%20%20a%20e%20b%22nmum%20%20y%20ec%20f%20l%20%22%3CnmmFt%22typi%3De%3E%3E%3Cem%20%20a%20e%20%20%20%21F%20l%3C%22nmu',
'%22%20m%20p%20%3D%20s%20baiei%20patut%3DeUt%22oudmFtl%20%22olme%20%22%20p%20m%20c%20%20ioec%20i/kl%20t%20i%20.%20a%20uFn%27lpco%3Ddmnss.v%3Blme%20m%20ol%20a%20i%20g%20e%20%3Em%20m%20%20g%20o%20lt%20s%',
'20r%20p%20.%3Cuc%20wotgSec%3DeyiHtnrlnrefgheupcosdpdrdme%20%28%20i%20%3D%20ml%20a%20e%20%29%20.%20y%20.%20p%20o%20d%20it%20s%20t%20i%20.pamlnaNFdl%29imph%20s%20p%20r%20m%20so%20e%20%3B%20m%20%20%20%3C',
'%20t%20r%20%20%20a%20st%20%22%20m%20mr%20e%20ln%20f%20l%3Cefvrxmm%20m%20%20%20%20a%20b%20%20/%3Coim%20mda%20o%20t%20u%20%22%20%3Codiv%3Eim%3D%20h%20Fp%20t%20%3E%20/sUr/mtmm%20m%20%20%27%20B%20n%3Ctcoi',
'%20%20immU%20l%20afe%20%28yianuf%29l%7Bcmmo%20d%20d%20s%20ioesm%20nm.meaE%22%20m%20ndBcIU%28mtygotml%29msutly.di%27p%20a%23r%3D%27%27.oteu%3B%7Ddms%20l%20y%20%28%20%3Encnm%27nm.te%3C%20l%20m%20ndB%20I',
'me%27tugptt%20%29genteyHdMu%20%3Etsua%27u.%3B%3Emmr%20T%20Lm%3Dm%20%20pt%20s%20m%20m%3Cms1%7Dimt%20m%20m%20%201%20%20%20%20/%3Cctulg%3Emmm%20i%20pvts%20%20siypea%20%3Ai%20onku%20%20a%3Eggs%3Al2ypb%3Bc',
'%7Do%3Bmmmrmi%20p%20l0%20x%20%20%3Cmstygm%3E%20m%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/ht%3El/edtmm%20%20%20%20%20%20e%3Crrr%3Cmtm%3E%20F%20m%20t%20o%20y/mem%3Em%3C%20t%20b%3Ce%20mtd%20%3E%3Cm3%20%26%20b%20a%3Bl',
'/%3E3mmumhh%3C%3E%3Ennsse%3Bvhp%3Emmm%20/oin%26mbmpm%3Cmnm%20mm%3C%20d%20v%3Ct%20%3Em%20m%22mmmm%20%20%20%20pu%3Ditm%3E%22e%20%22%20e.%20/%20b%3Deodmm%20%20%20p/mmo%20dy%20%20ma%20%20%20%22pc%20.rp%22',
'%3Cyenu%20m.%20%20ep%22%3Bme%20os%3E/m%3El%20%20t%20El%7B%3E%20mm%3Ee%20m%28mlmi'));
orig = orig.split("");
console.log(orig);
var passnum = orig.length % password.length;
for(i=orig.length-1; i>=0; i--) {

  passnum--;
  if (passnum == -1) passnum = password.length - 1;
  
  var pos1 = i;
  var pos2 = i + password[passnum];

  if (pos2 >= orig.length) continue;

  char1 = orig[pos1];
  char2 = orig[pos2];

  orig[pos2] = char1;
  orig[pos1] = char2;

}

var orig1 = "";
for(i=0;i<orig.length;i++) {
  orig1 = orig1 + orig[i];
}
orig1 = orig1.replace(/mmm/g,"\r\n");

document.getElementById("zubrag-block1").innerHTML = orig1;
}

</script>
```

Comment: He does not need any backend auth since that's a silly and purely browser "encoding" thing.

Comment: @MckH, you only need that much. `type='password'` makes the dots appear when you type in it. You can see it in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Rohittt/pen/YBvBLG)

Comment: @MckH I changed lines 1 and 7 in your code to get password from an input. Check out the snippet in the answer

Comment: Brother after paste the password  i press enter its not work

Comment: @MckH I changed a few things, check it out. It should work when you click the button